# Codeigniter 3 password_verify() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter-3, password-hash

I'm stuck creating a login system in CI.

I've got 2 errors:-
  Error 1: password_verify() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given
 Please can someone advise what i'm missing. I've poured through multiple forums and pages on google but can't seem to find the answer that fits. Please could one of you kind folk advise where i might be going wrong.

Controller:

```
public function auth()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
    $password = password_verify($this->input->post('password', TRUE));
    $validate = $this->model('Loginmodel')->validate($email,$password);
    if ($validate->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data        = $validate->row_array();
        $fname       = $data['fname'];
        $email       = $data['email'];
        $user_level  = $data['user_level'];
        $companyname = $data['companyname'];
        $mobileno    = $data['mobileno'];
        $avatar      = $data['avatar'];
        $sesdata     = array
```

Model:

```
class Loginmodel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function validate ($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('passwword', $password);
        $result = $this->db->get('dealers');
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, is this really the name of your password column? `passwword`, with 2 w's.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner my bad, it was a typo. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your problem is in this piece of code:

> password_verify($this->input->post('password', TRUE));

Its expecting second parameter of the password hash for verification, so you need to have it to be stored somewhere in database beforehand and retrieve it to pass to

> password_verify()

method as second parameter.

Comment: What you posted is more a comment, IMHO.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: I was just trying to help this guy. And I don`t have enough reputation for commenting, oh well.

Comment: Thanks Fsoc, much appreciated.